# Как правильно анимировать открытие диалогового окна в android compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, анимация, android-jetpack-compose

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно анимировать открытие диалогового окна android compose. Казалось, что надо следовать следующим образом:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = showDialog,
                    enter = описание анимации открытия,
                    exit = описание анимации закрытия
                ) {
                    Dialog(){ ... }
                    }
```

Но данный метод не работает, окно просто открывается и всё.
Я придумал как делать по другому, но кажется это костыль, а именно запихнуть анимацию внутрь диалогового окна добавив LaunchedEffect

```
Dialog(onDismissRequest = { showDialog = false }) {
                var startAnimation by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
                    startAnimation = true
                }
                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = startAnimation ,
                    enter = описание анимации открытия
                ) {
                    Контент диалогового окна
                    }
            }
```

Это очень похоже на костыль + надо думать как делать анимацию закрытия.